# Seeking hosted web application to import and search a spreadsheet

Tags: web-apps

I've got a simple use case. I have a spreadsheet that I want to import into a hosted service and I want to be able to design a search form and a results form for the imported data. The form needs to be password protected.

I've tried Airtable and the layout of the search results page is awful. I've tried mytaskhelper and the documentation is awful and I can't figure out how to import their search widget.

Suggestions?